# Vue.js filter not working with property[index]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

So I have this filter in computed property. It is not working if I use `{{ this.userInfo[index].DisplayName }}`. If I type anything into search field it will always give the first data. But it is working fine if I change it to `{{ user.DisplayName }}`. I'm using the first one because I need to do update which it refer with the [index]. How do I make the filter work with using `{{ this.userInfo[index].DisplayName }}`?

```js
computed: {
    filterUserInfo() {
      const value =
        this.searchQuery.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + this.searchQuery.slice(1);
      let reactiveArray = this.userInfo.filter(function (user) {
        return user.DisplayName.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
      if (reactiveArray.length > 0) {
        return reactiveArray;
      } else {
        return this.userInfo;
      }
    },
  }
```

And this is my v-for loop.

```html
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(user, index) in filterUserInfo.sort((a,b) => a.DisplayName > b.DisplayName ? 1 : -1)" :key="index">
    <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ this.userInfo[index].DisplayName }}</td>
    <td class="d-flex justify-content-around">
      <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-user-pen" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-toggle="toggle" data-placement="top" title="Edit Name" :data-bs-target="'#editmodal' + this.userInfo[index].Guid"/>
      <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-user-lock"  data-bs-toggle="modal" data-toggle="toggle" data-placement="top" title="Change Password" :data-bs-target="'#editpasswordModal' + this.userInfo[index].Guid"/>
      <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-trash" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-toggle="toggle" data-placement="top" title="Delete User" :data-bs-target="'#deleteModal' + this.userInfo[index].Guid"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Why you need to filter in ```this.userInfo[index].DisplayName``` if you already have ```v-for```?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you calling your data when looping, so i made this one. This is just a sample filtering base on your problem, so you can use it as your reference.

*In your template.*

```
<v-text-field 
    prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify position-left" 
    outlined dense label="Search"
    v-model="search"
    clearable
    color="blue-grey darken-4"
    background-color="cyan lighten-4"
    class="search mb-2 mt-0 pt-0"
    hide-details
></v-text-field>    
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>No.</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(user, index) in filterUserInfo" :key="index">
    <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.DisplayName }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.DisplayAge }}</td>
    <td class="d-flex justify-content-around"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

*I made this sample data in script.*

```
search:null,
userInfo:[
  { DisplayName:'John', DisplayAge: 20 },
  { DisplayName:'Andrew', DisplayAge: 21 },
  { DisplayName:'Michael', DisplayAge: 22 },
]
```

*Then, here's how I filter.*

```
computed: {
  filterUserInfo() {
    if(this.search){
      return this.userInfo.filter((item) => {
        return (
          this.search.toLowerCase().split("").every((v) =>
          item.DisplayName.toLowerCase().includes(v)) ||
          this.search == (item.DisplayAge)
        )
      })
    }
    else{
      return this.userInfo
    }
  }
}
```

And this is how it looks like.
[image]

**Additional**
You should make your function in *script* not on the *template*. Also, please attach image/draft of the final output to easily understand what you want to achieve.